# SQLite.Net UTC DateTime

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework-4.1, system.data.sqlite

I am writing an Entity Framework 4.1 application.  In this application I have a `History` class defined as follows:

```
public class History
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime HistoryDate { get; set; }
}
```

However, when I look in the database, it appears to store the date as local time.  My company doesn't exist in one time zone and so will this cause issues?  Is there something more I need to do to store the date and time as UTC, or is it already stored as UTC in SQLite and I'm just seeing the result in my local time.  Here is some sample output of what I see:

```
select id, historydate from history limit 1;
000846d3-f91d-47bb-9963-baf9530e0229|2004-10-28 16:57:00
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Store the date in UTC, and use the ToLocalTime when accessing the value to have it in local time:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tolocaltime.aspx

Comment: That's too bad.  I was hoping there may have been some method or trick that would store it as UTC in the database and then have System.Data.SQLite pick up on that flag.  Same in reverse, I was hoping that by providing a universal time, it would flag it as such.  Oh well.  Thanks for the input!

Comment: @Terry As of Mar 2015, SQLite has a flag to coerce dates to one TZ or another